# Overwriting Nan values with .loc in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-loc

I tried to solve the required task with the following code line:

`df['Age'][np.isnan(df["Age"])] = rand1`

[image]

But this raises a "SettingWithCopyWarning" and I think locating the Nan values in the dataframe (Column 'Age') by using the `.loc` feature might be a better way of doing this.

I already took a look at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), but still don't know how I can fix this problem. Couldn't find any solutions on here with `.loc` either.

I would appreciate any hints and advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN` to some value:

```
df.Age = df.Age.fillna(rand1)
```

Your solution with `loc`:

```
df.loc[np.isnan(df["Age"]), 'Age'] = rand1
#same as
#df.loc[df["Age"].isnull(), 'Age'] = rand1
```

You can also check [indexing view versus copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[20,23,np.nan]})
print (df)
    Age
0  20.0
1  23.0
2   NaN

rand1 = 30
df.Age = df.Age.fillna(rand1)
print (df)
    Age
0  20.0
1  23.0
2  30.0
```

---

```
#if need cast to int
df.Age = df.Age.fillna(rand1).astype(int)
print (df)
   Age
0   20
1   23
2   30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Code works perfectly fine. Can you please explain what is happening inside the .loc function? I initially thought it's for accessing indexes such as Age. Why are we passing in the .isnan part and then once again the Age column? Really have a hard time understanding this, even after reading the documentation.

Comment: Ok, it works because `np.isnan(df['Age'])` return boolean mask and with combination with `loc` set values to `rand1` where `True` values. I think better explanation is in this [pandas tutorial](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) - check title `SettingWithCopy` (there use another mask `f['a'] <= 3` instead `np.isnan(df['Age'])`)

Comment: And this tutorial is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) - `modern pandas` (very nice explanations)